# Deleting a range of entries from a Redis Stream

Tags: redis, redis-streams

I want to delete entries of a Redis Stream older than a particular entry ID. But the XDEL command takes each ID explicitly as input. Is there any way to specify a range of IDs which will help when there are large number of entries in the stream? Also trimming a range of entries will also help me recollect unsed memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there's no way.

> However, XTRIM is designed to accept different trimming strategies,
>   even if currently only MAXLEN is implemented. Given that this is an
>   explicit command, it is possible that in the future it will allow to
>   specify trimming by time, because the user calling this command in a
>   stand-alone way is supposed to know what she or he is doing.
>
> One useful eviction strategy that XTRIM should have is probably the
>   ability to remove by a range of IDs. **This is currently not possible,
>   but will be likely implemented in the future** in order to more easily
>   use XRANGE and XTRIM together to move data from Redis to other storage
>   systems if needed.

You can use XTRIM to claim the space, in XTRIM you can give the desired length.

`XTRIM mystream MAXLEN ~ 1000`

In this 1000 is the size of remaining stream, it could be more or less, it's an approximate number.

Ref: https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro